# Extract multiple strings using Regex jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following JSON response.

```
{ "Customer1": { "details": { "acc": { "number": "91422915166" }, "phone": { "number": "98400915180" } }, "DateofBirth": "1979-04-03", "firstName": "Harry", "lastName": "Potter" } }
```

Jmeter script structure:

```
Thread group (Get customer details)
+Regular expression extractor
.....name: customer
.....expression:"number":(.+?)"DateofBirth":"(.+?)"
.....MatchNo: -1
```

I want to use an extractor expression that only extracts the Phone "number". My present code is extracting both acc "number" and phone "number". Can you please tell me what expression I need to use in order to get this working? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the first number in your response is account number. You don't want that. If so

```
Expression : "phone": { "number": "(\d+)" }
```

should help.

P.S. : In your expression you also have DateofBirth in the expression. You needed only the number and not DateofBirth. If you want to extract two variables with multiple occurrences, I have tutorial exactly for that here. http://goo.gl/w3u1r

Comment: I want to extract only the second number..which is the phone number in the JSON response. The expression suggested above is still extracting both the numbers. Can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: It does work for me. Only change I had to make is MatchNo: 1. I have this gist depicting it. https://gist.github.com/msapariya/70b605063a4d43df29f3 I have used dummysampler from jmeter-plugins, you can replace that with your request. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to extract 2 values phone number and date of birth. Can you please help me do that?